# Deploying React frontend & Express backend on VPS server (ubuntu 16.04) using NGINX

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nginx, deployment

its my first time trying to deploy an app, and i have a VPS server running Ubuntu 16.04 to deploy my react app in. I am using NGINX to do so, and below is my config for the sites-available:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   root </build directory>;
   server_name <my server's IP>;
   server_name <myserverdomain.com>;
   index index.html;
   location / {
     try_files $uri /index.html =404;
   }
   location /backend {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect off;
 }
}
```

The frontend works with this, but i can't seem to be able to get my Express backend to work. Originally, my frontend calls my backend using a `fetch` command on the localhost:5000 (which is where my backend is listening). I have just been googling so I decided to give it a /backend path to reach it, so now its calling `fetch` on `<myserverdomain.com/backend/apicall>`.

However, despite running my backend on the localhost inside the VPS server, the api calls doesn't get redirected to my VPS's server localhost. Instead, when accessing the webapp from outside the VPS server on my local computer, its trying to look for the localhost:5000 on my local computer instead. As such, the API calls to the backend only works if my local computer is running the express backend. However, this is not desired as other users wouldn't have access to it.

I am really confused as to what is the correct way to implement this/ how do i properly 'host' my express backend server?

Comment: Maybe the problem is with your frontend configs? For example you need to set API url in appsettings.json to `myserverdomain.com/backend` instead of localhost ?

Comment: @mgsxman hey man thanks alot of the reply! Yes you're right! I was being dumb and did not update my build on the VPS server. However, after trying again i realised that the <domain.com>/backend is unreachable. I havent had a lot of time to try this yet, but if theres anything obvious that is wrong with my config above do point it out :) I will update here again if i make any progress